Does Hive supports information schema?
I want to query all tables/columns metadata in hive. The way this is done in other databases like mssql, postgresql is to query information_schema views, but i don't see anything like that in hive.
Can someone confirm is information_schema doesn't exists in hive. If it doesn't exists what would be a way to query metadata ??
0: jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10000/> select * from information_schema.tables;
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'tables' (state=42S02,code=10001)


Tried querying information_schema, but didn't get anything.

from your question it would appear that you've done no basic research/online-querying, Suggest you look at the official documentation https://hive.apache.org/ wrt the 'metastore'

Have read official documentation, didn't find anything regards to that.
